# OnCreateView() not called on click of "Up" button

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I have 2 fragments.
Clicking on a button in the first fragment takes you to the 2nd fragment.
By clicking the "UP" button in the 2nd fragment you'll get navigated back to the first fragment. Unfortunately the OnCreateView() method of the first fragment is not called.
Is there a way to call it? Which methods are called by clicking the "up" button?

Comment: Use replace method and add fragment in backstack so it will call onCreateView().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be called since 1st fragment is not yet detached from its activity and not destroyed yet. In your case, onResume() callback would be the best place to put your code.

Answer (score 1):

OnCreateView doesnt get called because the fragment A is already created.
Read about the Fragmetn/Activity lifecycle and u will understand that.
OnResume will get called once pressed back from Fragment B, so u can put your logic in that method.